# How to add &emsp; using appendChild in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

Let's say I want to append a pattern like this in the DOM:

```
*
*    *
*    *    *
*    *    *    *
```

My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
function tri1()
{
    let rows=document.getElementById("upperTri").value;
    for(let i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    {
        for (let j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            document.getElementById("resTri1").appendChild(document.createTextNode(star));
        }
        document.getElementById("resTri1").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
var star="*";
```

The thing is that I want to insert em space after each asterisk printed in the pattern, but HTML doesn't let one add more than one space unless it's an `&emsp;`, etc. But I couldn't find any way to `appendChild()` the emspace `&emsp;` in the DOM. It just prints the text `&emsp;` instead of the em space.

Any solution to this?

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pattern</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PB220322.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JS Lab Session 22-03-22</h1>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Left Triangle</h2></legend>
        <label for="upperTri">Enter the number of rows:</label>
        <input type="number" name="upperTri" id="upperTri" onchange="tri1()">
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" onsubmit="tri1()">
        <div id="resTri1"></div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Append to the `innerHTML` of the parent element after appending the text node:

```js
function tri1()
{
    let rows=document.getElementById("upperTri").value;
    for(let i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    {
        for (let j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
          
            let elem = document.getElementById("resTri1")
            elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(star));
            elem.innerHTML += "&emsp;"
        }
        document.getElementById("resTri1").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
var star="*";
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pattern</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JS Lab Session 22-03-22</h1>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Left Triangle</h2></legend>
        <label for="upperTri">Enter the number of rows:</label>
        <input type="number" name="upperTri" id="upperTri" onchange="tri1()">
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" onsubmit="tri1()">
        <div id="resTri1"></div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Really quick:**

[Inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) so in the example that `onchange` and `onsubmit` have been replaced with [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

`.createTextNode()` is quite antiquated, albiet very stable, it renders text not HTML. `.innerHTML` and `.textContent` can destroy content if it isn't appended with a `+=` operand. There is a method that isn't destructive and very versatile: [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). The [Unicode characters](http://www.amp-what.com/) you are trying to use can be in different formats:

```
// HTML Decimal & Hexidecimal
&ast;&emsp;
// CSS
\00002a\002003
// JavaScript
\u002a\u2003
```

`&ast;&emsp;` needs to be rendered as HTML so methods such as `.insertAdjacentHTML()` is ideal, but more often you'll see `.innerHTML` being used despite it's limitations.

The example below employs some useful interfaces from the [HTML DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API). There are extensive details commented in the example -- the following list are references pertaining to those comments:

- [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)
- [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [HTMLFormElement Submit Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)
- [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
- [Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

<sup>***Note:** in the example the "stars" are just a fancier asterisk ❉.*</sup>

```js
// Event handler passes the Event Object
function tri(e) {
  /*
  Stop the default behavior of form#UI✺ during a "submit" event.
  */
  e.preventDefault();

  // Create a HTMLFormControlsCollection (>this< is form#UI)
  const IO = this.elements;
  /*
  The value of input#rQty coerced into a real number 
  (prefixed with a plus '+' will coerce a string into number)
  */
  const rows = +IO.rQty.value;
  // ❉ and emspace in HTML decimal format;
  const star = '&#10057;&emsp;';

  for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      /*
      iAHTML() renders htmlString into real HTML without destroying 
      content (unlike .innerHTML) 
      */
      IO.box.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', star);
    }
    IO.box.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<br>');
  }

}

/*
Bind form#UI to the "submit" event.
When "submit" event fires, the event handler tri(e) will be invoked.
Note the terse syntax of the DOM Object:
document.forms.UI 
this is from the HTMLFormElement interface.
*/
document.forms.UI.addEventListener('submit', tri);

/*
✺ form#UI is also >this< within the event handler because it is registered
to the "submit" event.
*/
/*
 HTMLFormControlsCollection is part of the HTMLFormElement interface. It 
is an array-like object consisting of all form controls under form#UI. Form 
controls are:
<button>, <fieldset>, <input>, <object>, <output>, <select>, <textarea>
form controls may be referrenced by id or by name.
*/
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1.15 'Segoe UI';
}

header {
  margin-bottom: -12px;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

fieldset {
  min-width: max-content;
}

legend {
  margin-bottom: -12px;
}

label,
input {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#rQty {
  width: 5ch;
  text-align: right;
}

.box {
  font-family: Consolas;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JS Lab Session 22-03-22</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
    /* Any CSS here has second highest priority */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='UI'>
    <header>
      <h1>JS Lab</h1>
      <p>Session 22-03-22</p>
    </header>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h2>Left Triangle</h2>
      </legend>
      <label for="rQty">Enter the number of rows: </label>
      <input id="rQty" type="number" min='3' max='100' value='3'>
      <input type="submit" value="Enter">
      <fieldset name="box" class='box'></fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
    /* 
    JavaScript can go here. 
    Place all external script tags directly above/before this 
    script tag.
    */
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```